# Open your own application via URL schemes

Tags: ios, swift, url

I am trying to open my application from the same application while app is in background. Is that possible? If not, how can I reopen/reactivate/resume the app?

**Suspend and resume is user-activated**

I filled the info.plist with the urls and schemes, and I did:

```
let hook = "myapp://hello"
let url = URL(string: hook)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!){
    print("opening...")
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: { (finished) in
        print("finished?: \(finished)")
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)            
    })
} else {
    print("App not installed")
}
```

But the completitionHandler says: `finished?: false`

Thank you.

Comment: Only the user can bring an app to the foreground by launching it from its icon, a notification or the app switcher. These are the ways that the user activates an app, and iOS will do what you want when the user does this.